# How to overload '==' operator within a struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct which I wish to use to remove items from a vector, I do not know what index the item will appear at so I'm removing it by value. Here is my struct:

```
struct IsUnderScore{
bool operator()(char c){
    return c=='_';
}
};
```

I can use this struct to remove values from strings but when I try to use on a vector like so:

```
abc.erase(std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), IsUnderScore()), abc.end());
```

I get a compiler error saying there is no match for the == operator.

So I know I have to overload this operator itself, and in looking at some of the other implementations of it throughout SO, can't really find an implementation that matches my case, most other versions have variables declared in their structs but this is a simple bool to see if the current character matches underscore. I'm kind of confused as how I should build my overload to match my case.

**EDIT**: The vector in question is a vector string by the way.

Comment: In `IsUnderScore` there is no implementation of `operator==` but of `operator()`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Codor: No, `remove_if` expects something callable (i.e. a function, or a class with `operator()`). `remove` expects a value to compare with, not a predicate, which is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with a missing `operator==`, but with using the wrong function+argument pair. `remove()` takes an *item* as the 3rd argument, not a predicate. For a predicate, you need `remove_if`. So do one of these:

```
std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), '_')

// or

std::remove_if(abc.begin(), abc.end(), IsUnderScore())
```

**EDIT**

The 3rd parameter of `remove` is of the type of the iterator's value type. The parameter of the predicate used in `remove_if` takes the same type. Based on your edit, this is `std::string` in your case, so you must use it accordingly. Either use `remove` with a string:

```
std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), "_")

// or 

std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), std::string("_"))
```

Or update the predicate for use with `remove_if`:

```
struct IsUnderScore{
  bool operator()(const std::string &s){
    return s == "_";
  }
};

// ...

std::remove_if(abc.begin(), abc.end(), IsUnderScore())
```

Comment: I tried using both methods here, when trying to use the first method, I received the same error as above, in regards to overloading the == operator. But when using the second method I receive a no match to call IsUnderScore() error.

Comment: @liquid That's something you should mention in the question, and also copy the *exact and unedited* error message you get *in each case.* I doubt they're the same.

Comment: See edit, I posted my comment before it completed, after reading your response I tried both methods and received errors.

Comment: @liquid Edited the answer. The "by the way" piece of info is vital. That's why you should *always* post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) when asking about an error.

Comment: sorry for the late response. Your edited answer compiled without any warnings, thanks for the input. However, it seems that it's causing a memory leak, when running my program it halts during the removal of '_' in vector, and when running it gdb I get a segfault which backtraced to a memory leak.

Comment: @liquid That's a separate issue. Debug it, isolate it, search and if you can't reach a solution yourself, you're welcome to ask a separate question about it (which will include all your findings from the steps I mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

You use `std::remove` - it does not use the comparator as the third argument, but just the value to remove. Assuming that your `abc` vector is `vector<char>` use

```
std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying `remove` instead `remove_if`. (Or you are trying `remove` with a functor, instead a char).

The best and simple solution:

```
abc.erase(std::remove(abc.begin(), abc.end(), '_'), abc.end());
```

The alternative (not too useful here, but just in case you need a more complex comparison to determine what element to remove):

```
abc.erase_if(std::remove_if(abc.begin(), abc.end(), IsUnderScore()), abc.end());
```