# Memory leak caused by removing value from vector

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

A few days ago I asked for help in removing a value from a vector by value instead of it's index, see thread here ( [How to overload '==' operator within a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294364/how-to-overload-operator-within-a-struct/23294501?noredirect=1#comment35682176_23294501) )

I was able to get a solution to compile thanks to the help of Angew, the solution is marked as 'answered' in the thread.

However, when executing my program with this fix, my program halts unexpectedly, and when running it through a debugger, it seems that the fix caused a memory leak, could anyone provide insight about how this could occur?

Once again, here is my struct that I use to find the value I'm trying to remove:

```
struct IsUnderScore{
bool operator()(char c){
    return c=='_';
}
};
```

I can use it on a string using the erase-remove idiom very easily like so:

```
string.erase(remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), IsUnderScore()), string.end());
```

but when using it on a vector I had compiler issues which were solved like so:

```
vector.erase(std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::string("_")));
```

And now I get a memory leak.

EDIT: Here is a copy of the error given by gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaab917ee8 in std::string::_Rep::_M_is_leaked ()
```

Comment: What do you mean by memory leak? I don't see any `new` in your code, which would be a prerequisite for memory leaks.

Comment: This confuses me as well, I am not doing any low-level memory management in my code, however when I implemented the fix above, my program compiled but halted when it came across this code, I checked it using gdb and the debugger complained of a memory leak.

Comment: Can you try to run it with a valgrind? looks strange... What do you have in your vector?

Comment: memory leak or segmentation fault?

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/) would be useful.

Comment: It's not complaining about a leak, you have a segmentaion fault inside an internal function, `_M_is_leaked`, that the `string` implementation in your library uses. It seems that the internal memory buffer of the string has become corrupted. How is impossible to tell without more code and information about *where* this happened in your code, but I would start with checking that all `delete`s are good, that you're never using an uninitialized pointer, and that a reference or pointer to a local variable hasn't snuck in somewhere.

Comment: A segmentation fault is not the same as a memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has a potential problem:

```
vector.erase(std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::string("_")));
```

If the `std::remove` doesn't match any elements it returns `vector.end()`. Erasing an `end()` iterator is undefined behavior and a segfault can be the result.

I think you want the two-argument overload of `std::vector::erase` since it can handle an empty range. It's also the correct thing to do in case `std::remove` matches multiple elements...

```
vector.erase(std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::string("_")), vector.end());
```

Comment: Ah I see, so it seems that trying to remove the end() iterator caused the issue, using your example the code compiles and executes to spec, thanks for the help, I will try to keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @liquid: If you check some [good documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) it should say that `end()` can't be used with the single argument `erase()`.